# MATCH AGAINST get results matching several words in correct order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has `terms`, these terms are actually possible search inputs added by users, looks similar to:

```
| id  | name          | remote_id  | type       |
| --- | ------------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 1   | Audi          | 3453       | category   |
| 2   | Audi RS       | 52434      | model      |
| 3   | Las Vegas     | 30         | city       |
| 4   | 1994          | 10         | production |
| 5   | Audi for sale | 3454       | category   |
| 6   | Audi for rent | 3455       | category   |
```

I want to create a simple method to let the user have a good search result for this kind of input:

`Audi for sale 1994 in Las Vegas`

I want to get the minimum result from the table that matches the input sentences, my required result is:

```
1- Audi for sale
2- 1994
3- Las Vegas
```

But i couldn't get this result, as what I tried is using:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `terms` WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('Audi for sale 1994 in Las Vegas' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
```

But then I got results I don't want such as `Audi, Audi RS, Audi for rent`.

According to what I [read here](https://www.mullie.eu/mysql-as-a-search-engine/), I tried to split the input sentence as the following, and adding `+` before every word then search trying to mach all of them:

```
+Audi
+Audi +for
+Audi +for +sale
+Audi +for +sale +1994
+Audi +for +sale +1994 +in
+Audi +for +sale +1994 +in +Las
+Audi +for +sale +1994 +in +Las +Vegas
```

I tried as the following to guarantee the order of the words to match the records in my table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `terms` WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('(+Audi) (+Audi +for) (+Audi +for +sale) (+Audi +for +sale +1994) .....' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But then this also made some expected results get lost, like `1994` and `Las Vegas`.

I hope I could explain what I'm trying to achieve correctly, thanks.

**EDIT**

Let me be more clear and add some more details, the point is to avoid that users use FILTERS in my website to find the cars, like instead of selecting Audi, then selecting "RS", then selecting "Las Vegas" and the production year "1994", I want to make the user able to search for `Audi for sale 1994 in Las Vegas` in a single text box, and filtering should be done in the back end to separate and classify the correct categories and parameters to use in the search process.

If I could define that "Audi for sale" is the `category`, "1994" is the `production`, and "Las Vegas" is the `city`, I then can simply build the query that could get the correct result for the user without him to filter manually.

Comment: Can you define more precisely what you mean by 'the minimum result from the table that matches the input sentences'?

Comment: Sure, in short, I want to get only the rows related to what the user typed, exactly in the correct order, I want to get "Audi for sale" only, without getting "Audi" row or "Audi RS" because they are not typed in the input.

Comment: I guess by "related" you mean that they appear in the input. "Audi" appears in the input. I guess you want to get "Audi for sale" and not "Audi" because "Audi" is also a part of "Audi for sale". What is the expected output if your rows are "Audi for" and "for sale" and the user types "Audi for sale"? What is the expected output if your only row is "Audi for sale" and the user just types "Audi"?

Comment: User types "Audi for sale", the best result should match from my rows is "Audi" of course...... For the last question if only row "Audi for sale" exist and user types "Audi", that only row should come up, but as far as I know this requires another code to do it. So i don't mind if nothing come up.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough with my question. I mean imagine you have only two rows in your database, which are "Audi for" and "for sale". The user types "Audi for sale". What should be the result?

Comment: Nothing sir, no result should come up because "Audi for sale" is not exist as a common term, the whole idea is to find the "EXACT" terms in any sentence the user input and match them in the rows. So in case user searched for "Audi for sale bla bla bla" in a table that has "Audi" and "Audi for sale" in it, only "Audi for sale" should come up, as it is the exact mach of what the user typed between the terms.

Comment: So you're telling me that if the user types "Audi for sale" and the database has a row which is "Audi for" then nothing will come up. But if the user types "Audi for sale bla bla bla" and the database has "Audi for sale" then "Audi for sale" comes up. This is contradictory. Sorry to be so pestering, but if you don't define the problem unambiguously, covering all corner cases (and not just your ideal example) there is no way we can find a solution.

Comment: It seems you are right, so I am updating my question now again below to add more details about what I am trying to do exactly. thank you for paying attention, I will let you know when I'm done in few minutes.

Comment: Please, take another look at my updates at the end. I appreciate your kind help.