# match any terms in text to a ready list of terms

Tags: php, arrays, substring, string-matching

I have an array of terms:

```
$arr = [
  'black',
  'white and black',
  'lion',
  'fast',
  'zebra',
  'lion is fast',
  'zebra is white'
];
```

I want to filter this array according to a specific sentence, for example:

`zebra is white and black, and lion is fast`

I tried using `strpos` and some regex functions, but I didn't get the expected result. What I am expecting is to get the `minimum` amount of items in the list that matches parts of the sentence IN ORDER, which would be:

```
[
  'white and black',
  'zebra',
  'lion is fast'
]
```

That way I could separate the result to match parts from the sentence as:

`\zebra\ is \white and black\, and \lion is fast\`

and ignore other items in the array as they don't fully match.

Can you please lead me to the correct way to do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to add your already attempted code snippets.

Comment: It was a loop through the array items, and trying to 'strpos' them in the sentence, it was directly obvious that some other items in the list are matching, like `black` and `lion`... I will post it anyway.

Comment: What is the expected output? You have two items with `lion` is both supposed to be in the output?

Comment: I have but arrows beside the expected outputs in my question `<<<<<-----`, no, only `lion is fast` should match because it is the full term that matches, not `lion` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the array on lenght and loop it.
When you find the array item in the string save it to the new array and remove the substring from the string.

At the end of the code you will get an array of the matching items.

```
$arr = ['black',
'white and black',
'lion',
'fast',
'zebra',
'lion is fast',
'zebra is white'];

$str = "zebra is white and black, and lion is fast";

function sortl($a,$b){
    return strlen($b)-strlen($a);
}

usort($arr,'sortl');

foreach($arr as $s){
    if(strpos($str, $s) !== false){
        $new[] = $s;
        $str = str_replace($s, "", $str);
    }
}

var_dump($new);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "white and black"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "lion is fast"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "zebra"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/7iTHC

Comment: That was very smart, thank you, is there a way I can achieve that with mySQL in my other question? would you mind to take a look please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025596/

Comment: @tinyCoder I don't have the skills for that in MySQL.

Comment: Andreas Thank you so much anyway, may I just finally ask if the array of terms was 2D and every term has an ID, like `[{id:12323,term:'white and black'}, {}....]` how would the above code look like?

Comment: Is id unique? If yes, then I would use array_column to make the array flat. `$arr = array_column($arr, "term", "id");` this makes the key id and value the term.

Comment: No it is not unique unfortunately, that is why I didn't wrote it as key=>value in my comment, multiple terms could have the same ID. Im afraid about the performance now if the list has more than 1000 items.

Comment: This is a cheap man's multidimensional array. I use [0] in my code but you need to replace that with ['term']. https://3v4l.org/KscS0 . About the performance, you could add a `if(trim($str) =="")` then exit the loop and at least it will not loop all items if it finds all.